# How to exclude first and last 150 rows from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with around 50-100k rows. How can I call a function X only for rows between the first 150 rows and the last 150 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with `iloc`

```
df.iloc[150:-150,:]
```

Comment: How can I do this for column ‘X’ only?

Comment: @dunkubok `df.iloc[150:-150]['X']`